# Ruled surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of high degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $S\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3(x:y:z:w)$ is a surface of degree $d$, which I assume to be integral as a scheme. So $S$ is the zero locus of a homogeneous polynomial in $k[x,y,z,w]$ of degree $d$ which generates a prime ideal. Here $k$ is the base field and is assumed to be algebraically closed.

> If $S$ is ruled (every point of $S$ is contained in a line $L\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ which is contained in $S$) and $d>2$, must $S$ be a cone? If not, is there a classification of such surfaces?

The only smooth ruled surfaces are planes and smooth quadrics. So any surface satisfying the above conditions must be singular, but beyond that I've been having trouble determining further properties they must satisfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one for you to play with: Consider the surface

$$z^2w^2+4x^3z-6xyzw+4y^3w - 3x^2y^2 = 0.$$

It's called a *tangent developable*, the surface of lines tangent to a smooth curve in $\Bbb P^3$. Can you find the curve?

Comment: Is the second term not supposed to have a w? With that edit, I think I understand. The dual of a smooth curve will be a surface, and is formed as the set of all tangent planes to the curve (planes containing the tangent lines). Each tangent line of the curve determines a line in dual projective space of the planes tangent to it, and thus the dual variety of the curve is a surface ruled by these lines. My computer algebra program can compute the dual of the given surface using elimination, and this gives a twisted cubic curve.

Comment: I also noticed that the underlying set of the singular locus of this surface is the twisted cubic defined by $(y^2 - xz, xy - zw, x^2 - yw)$. My guess is that this is the curve, but a proof that the singular loci of these tangent developable surfaces are the curves they came from escapes me at the moment. Either way, thanks for the example!

Comment: Yes, the $w$ in the second term was a typo. My apologies. Yes, this is the tangent developable of the twisted cubic. You can prove locally that the tangent developable is smooth away from the curve itself (when the curve is not degenerate). It is a local differential geometry exercise (either in Euclidean space or in projective space) that a ruled surface whose Gauss map is degenerate must be locally a cone, a cylinder, a plane, or a tangent developable. I haven't thought about a global characterization of generic ruled surfaces in $\Bbb P^3$.

Comment: By the way, you may find this pretty paper of [Griffiths and Harris](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/alggeom79.pdf) interesting. J.M. Landsberg has published numerous papers following various ideas in this paper, too.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The interplay between differential and algebraic geometry is fascinating to me. I read a paper by Landsberg a little while back which I think was using these kinds of techniques to study complete intersections.

Comment: To me too. That was most of my research activity ...